# Pandas Groupby count

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as follows (tail 10):

```
> store_id  period_id   sales_volume    t   unique_period   q4
> 809838    38126884    242 1.3485     1.0   211447000      1
> 643854    38126899    240 2.9500    777.0  211448500      1
> 227299    38126899    242 6.2000    777.0  211450000      1
> 731859    38126908    240 2.2000    777.0  211451500      1
> 687269    38126908    241 2.6000     1.0   211451500      1
> 512944    38126926    241 3.9500    777.0  211453000      1
> 832513    38126935    240 0.9500    777.0  211454500      1
> 417892    38126935    242 4.6500    777.0  211456000      1
> 354468    38126938    241 5.1000    777.0  211457500      1
> 604276    38126938    242 3.2765     1.0   211457500      1
```

I create a groupby object:

```
mc[['store_id', 'unique_period']].groupby(['store_id','unique_period']).count()
```

which results in:

```
store_id    unique_period
4168621     1000
            2500
            4000
            5500
            7000
            8500
4168624     10000
4168636     11500
            13000
            14500
```

But i need to count 'UNIQUE PERIOD' within each group eg:

group 4168621 - 6 records, 
group 4168624 - 1 record
and so on.

After that need to calculate MEDIAN on that series.

I m stuck. Since the GROUPBY has no values just GroupBY index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) with `median`:

```
a = mc.groupby('store_id')['unique_period'].nunique()
print (a)
store_id
38126884    1
38126899    2
38126908    1
38126926    1
38126935    2
38126938    1
Name: unique_period, dtype: int64

a = mc.groupby('store_id')['unique_period'].nunique().median()
print (a)
1.0
```

EDIT:

If need count unique values and median:

```
a = mc.groupby('store_id')['unique_period'].agg(['nunique','median'])
print (a)
          nunique     median
store_id                    
38126884        1  211447000
38126899        2  211449250
38126908        1  211451500
38126926        1  211453000
38126935        2  211455250
38126938        1  211457500
```

Comment: Sry but that s not what i need.

Comment: @Ciro - Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: In the groupby ['store_id] there are ONLY 6 unque records of ['unique_period']. And i need to calculate those within each unique ['store_id']

Comment: @Ciro - Can you check now?

Comment: God bless and heartly tons of thanks. I was deadly stuck on this question )))

Comment: @Ciro - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)